# Angular 4 Dependency Injection with Ajax Call

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I'm trying to get some `$_SESSION` variables from `PHP` to `Angular`. I created an `Injectable` class called `Globals` and defined this class in `Providers` of `AppModule`.

Here is my **globals.ts**:

```
import { Injectable }   from '@angular/core';

@Injectable ()
export class Globals {
    errorMessage: string;

    activeUser: any;

    test: string = "test string";

    constructor(private userService: UserService) {
        this.getActiveUser();

        console.log(this.activeUser); //undefined
    }

    getActiveUser(){
         this.userService.getActiveUser()
            .then(
                user => this.activeUser = user,
                error   => this.errorMessage = <any>error
            );
    }
}
```

The above logging command works after loading of the whole project completes. But it is a dependency for me and I get to have the returned value in my constructor.

An examplary component is below:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Globals }                   from "../globals";

@Component()
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
   constructor(
        private globals: Globals
    ) {
        console.log(this.globals.activeUser); //undefined

        console.log(this.globals.test); //"test string"
    }
}
```

I also created a plunker for this: https://embed.plnkr.co/zRmkQdfqYDBTAoQPqJ5V/

EDIT: I know that it is caused by **asynchronicity**, what I need is a solution to get `activeUser` before initialization

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: read up on asynchronicity :)

Comment: I know what asynchronicity is and I also know that this problem is caused by it. What I need is not a lesson about it, a solution instead.

Comment: You should read carefully @AJT_82 "The above logging command works after loading of the whole project completes. But it is a dependency for me and I get to have the returned value in my constructor."

Comment: Not my intention to any way be insulting or anything, so take it easy :) I assumed that the understanding of asynchronicity was perhaps not the best, as the problem clearly lies there and that you should return an Observable to your component instead.

Comment: And if you are looking for to actually get the data on initialization: `APP_INITIALIZER`

Comment: Can you describe your solution on the above plunker example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As AJT_82 proposed via comments, the problem is solved by APP_INITIALIZER.

First, I have imported `APP_INITIALIZER` on my **app.module.ts**:

```
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
```

Before `@NgModule()` function, I have included this:

`export function init_app(globals: Globals) {
    return () => globals.InitializeApp();
}`

Also in the `providers` section:

```
providers:[
    Globals,
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: init_app, deps: [Globals], multi: true },
]
```

Lastly, my **globals.ts**:

```
getActiveUser(resolver){
    this.userService.getActiveUser()
        .then(
            user => {
                this.activeUser = user;

                resolver();
            },
            error   => this.errorMessage = <any>error
        );
}

InitializeApp(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.getActiveUser(resolve);
    });
}
```